# Can we install R script or any third party software to CDH5 (Cloudera Distribution of Hadoop)

Tags: r, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I am going to setup a local cluster where i am planning to use CDH5. With this i will have all the inbuilt eco-system of hadoop on the fly however i need Rscript also in my cluster for some hadoop streaming and data analytics work. So just wondering is it possible to use CDH5 and install R script. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you will have to use RHadoop (https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki)

It runs on CDH. You can find more information about Cloudera and RHadoop here :

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/solutions/partner/Revolution-analytics.html